# toastr js CSS disable background-color on Rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, toastr

When I call toastr.error or the others (info, success...) the background-color is not respect (or it is disabled). It is "forced" to white. Show the inspect image bellow to understand (I hope). How may I resolve it?

[image]

Comment: I am using gem toastr-rails 1.0.3.
When I uncheck background-color of .toast in inspect, it is work ok.

Comment: Not sure how your other code looks like, it could be some order in the assets, something might be overwriting it, or the way you are calling toastr. You can always override it in your main assets `.toast-error { background-color: #BD#62F!important; }`

Answer (score 0):

I move `require toastr` in application.js and application.css to end of files and it is works properly.